# Why mosquitoes sit on wall vertically (head upper side)?

Tags: entomology

I was curious to know why mosquito sit on walls or trees vertically like head towards sky, unlike other insects like fly, ants, termites sit with any direction.

Also, what they do sitting doing nothing (rest/digestion may be)?